# What is the main use of Try & Catch in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I would like to know the main goal to use Try & Catch in Javascript, below is the example i am achieving

1. Should I need to let the program stop in case of error?
2. Why In programming I need to my application to continue running
   however there is an error?

```
  try {
    if (typeof a != "number") {
      throw new ReferenceError("The First argument is not a number");
    } else if (typeof b != "number") {
      throw new ReferenceError("The Second argument is not a number");
    } else {
      console.log(a + b);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error:", error.message);
  }
}

addTwoNums("10", 100);
console.log("It still works");
```

Comment: Is the operation critical to the outcome of your method? No - then continue processing and warn the user when complete. Yes - stop processing and show an error message. As with all things, it entirely depends on your use case.

Comment: Putting `throw` statements right inside the `try` block is pointless, you could have just called `console.log("… is not a number")` right away. You'd rather put the `try` block around the `addTwoNums(…)` call - it is the caller's decision what should happen when an exception occurs (or whether it should be caught at all), not the decision of the `addTwoNums` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the try block is executed first, and if it throws an exception, the code in the catch block will be executed. The code in the finally block will always be executed before control flow exits the entire construct

Answer (score 0):

There are some things in java that require `try` and `catch` statements to function, for instance if you wanted to read a file java will prevent you from doing so unless error catching is used.

In your example whilst there is no harm in using `try`, it is simply unnecessary as there is no variability in the success of your function. Also, since there is no need to stop the program if the arguments are invalid, instead of throwing errors it might be preferable to instead halt the operation and return a warning.

Comment: Thanks but what you means halt the operation and return a warning?

Comment: Instead of going on to add the parameters, return a string warning the user that they used incorrect function parameters.

Comment: The question is about JavaScript, not about Java.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry must have gotten confused, though (most of) the answer still applies.