# Throwing an error will stop the execution of the code [Javascript]

Tags: javascript

In this exercise I just did, throw an error still let the last `console.log("This is still runs normally!")` runs successfully but why the this question it is answer that throwing error stop the execution and no execution for `console.log`

Question I am confused about:

```
throw new Error();
console.log("Hello");
```

```
function addTwoNums(a, b) {
  try {
    if (typeof a != "number") {
      throw new ReferenceError("The First argument is not a number");
    } else if (typeof b != "number") {
      throw new ReferenceError("The Second argument is not a number");
    } else {
      console.log(a + b);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error:", error.message);
  }
}

addTwoNums("100", 100);
console.log("This is still runs normally!");
```

Comment: The error is being caught. I think if it didn’t get caught, the log wouldn’t happen

Comment: This is the whole point of `try`/`catch` - to allow you to _catch_ the error, handle it, and resume execution.

Comment: If you `catch` an error, code will continue executing as normal. If you don't want the final `console.log` to run you have to re-throw the error. eg add `throw error` as the last line in your `catch` block.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74079164/1048572)?

Comment: Thanks Bergi but no, not the same [I am trying to get full picture of error handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont really understand your question easily but i will try to answer two things :
in this first code you don't put throw error in a try catch, so if you execute it, the error stops the code before your console log.

```js
throw new Error(); //-> stop the code and goodbye
console.log("Hello");
```

in the second code, you catch the error and tell the program to console log the error message when and error is caught :

```js
} catch (error) { // <- if there is an error
    console.log("Error:", error.message); // <- then console log the error.message
```

so the program does the console log, and continues (and gets to your next console log "This is still runs normally!")

so the answer of your question about "why the error stops the code execution" is "becase its not caught or handled by a try-catch"